# For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 < |x_n - p| < \frac{1}{n}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = p$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let's say $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence. Then how to prove the following statement?

**"For all $\mathbf{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\mathbf{0 < |x_n - p| < \frac{1}{n}}$, then $\mathbf{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = p}$"**

If the sequence converges to $p$,
we need to show then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $|x_n - p| < \epsilon$ if $n \geq N$.

Intuitively, since $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$, so the sequence goes to $p$, but I have no idea of how to prove it strictly.

Comment: Use the definition of convergence. First, let $\varepsilon>0$. Now find $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|x_n-p|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is archimedean thus for any $\epsilon$ there exists $n$ such that $n\epsilon>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\varepsilon>0$ choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Comment: @shashack You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, the squeeze theorem gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n-p|=0$. This means that for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left||x_n-p|-0\right|=\left||x_n-p|\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Notice that $||x||=|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (this easily follows from any of the equivalent definitions of the absolute value function). Therefore,

$$\left||x_n-p|\right|=|x_n-p|<\varepsilon$$

It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=p$.